# how to get emails and their rights to a specific Notion page

Tags: c#, notion-api

I am writing a small project in c# to work with notion, I need to get the user's email and his rights from my page, there is a large nesting of pages in the project and I need to get emails and rights specifically for the page, the problem is that there are no suitable methods for this in the notion api, who knows how it can be solved?

I read all documentation to notion api and nothing that i need